# how to get the id of smallest number in mysql using the MIN() function

Tags: mysql, sql

sample table

```
id |   name   | price |
-----------------------
1  |   john   | 300   |
----------------------- 
2  | michael  |  400  |
----------------------- 
3  | michelle |  250  |
-----------------------
```

I will get the smallest number in the table using this query

```
SELECT id, name, MIN(price) FROM table
```

The result will become this:

```
_______________________
id |   name   | price |
-----------------------
1  | michelle |  250  |
```

---

I want the result will become like this:

```
id |   name   | price |
-----------------------
3  | michelle |  250  |
-----------------------
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: BTW, the lowest price in your sample dataset is 200, yet your desired output uses the price of 250. Is that an error, or do I not fully understand what you want?

Comment: I'd upvote this question, except your expected output doesn't match the question you're asking. (You're asking for the `MIN` price, but displaying output from something other than that, which makes no sense.)

Comment: Sorry I wrote a wrong value id 2 should be 400. Thanks for you suggestions.

Answer (score 8):

The easiest way to get the id of the smallest number is this:

```
SELECT Id, name, price
FROM sampleTable
ORDER BY price ASC 
LIMIT 1;
```

If you want to use MIN (as the title states), one way to do it would be this:

```
SELECT id, name, price 
FROM sampleTable 
WHERE price = (SELECT MIN(price) from sampleTable)
```

Comment: Thanks M_M for this query. I prefer to use the 1st query because I need also to get the smallest price and ID.

Answer (score 4):

Use a subquery:

```
SELECT id, name, price 
FROM table 
WHERE price = (SELECT min(price) FROM table);
```

Without a `LIMIT 1`, this can return multiple rows that all share the same minimum price.  This may or may not be what you want instead of a arbitrary choice among the matching records.

Comment: It should be `PRICE =` and not `PRICE IN`, since you're trying to match a single row.

Answer (score 3):

For this query, you do not need `MIN`, but can use `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT`

```
SELECT id, name, price
FROM Table
ORDER BY Price ASC
LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 3):

I do it this way:

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.name, t1.price
FROM sampleTable AS t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN sampleTable AS t2
  ON t1.price > t2.price
WHERE t2.id IS NULL
```

In other words, look for a row t2 that has a lower price than the row t1.  If no such row t2 is found, the outer join makes t2.* NULL, and when that's true, then t1 must have the minimum price.

This is called an **exclusion join** and it typically performs better than a subquery in MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

Do this;

```
SELECT id, name, price FROM table order by price ASC LIMIT 1
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Efficient way (with any number of records):-

```
SELECT id, name, MIN(price) FROM (select * from table order by price) as t group by id
```

I have tried many solutions:
using `join`, `subquery` .they all are good but consuming more time.

But this one is fabulous.